# Hibernate ignore field on certain condition

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate and I'm having a problem in persist. In user class, it has `first_name`, `last_name`, `gender`, `address`, etc and I want only `Address` column field to ignore update to table when user's `gender` is only equals to `Female`. I googled and found out that I can use `@Transient` to ignore update but what I want is to ignore when certain condition is met and if not, I want to include `Address` in persist.

Is it possible to do in hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring a field based of the value of another field in not the responsability of the [Data Access Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer). It should be the responsibility of the [Business Logic Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic).

When your condition is met, just erase the new address with a copy of the old one before persisting.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. then how about in select? is it possible to ignore selecting that field on condition?

Comment: @Raymond I don't undersand why you would do such a thing, but you can still set a field to null after select, or select the fields one by one and manually build objects using those fields.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to do this would be to amend the `setter` for address field. like

`public void setAddress(String address) {
     if(!this.gender.equals("female") {
         this.address = address;
     } 
 }`

So when you persist the `User` address value would not be there for female users.